# SED: using regex to replace arguments

Tags: sed

I have to replace a line in a config file.

this:

```
execution.commands=ARGUMENT,COMMAND,RULE
```

into this:

```
execution.commands=!ARGUMENT,!COMMAND,!RULE
```

Is it possible to do using sed and regex?

Thanks!

Comment: `sed 's/execution.commands=ARGUMENT,COMMAND,RULE/execution.commands=!ARGUMENT,!COMMAND,!RULE/' file`?

Comment: ARGUMENT,COMMAND,RULE aren't static. Sometimes could be just 1 instead 3 as well like this: execution.commands=COMMAND

Comment: @Robson, it will be good if you could mention all the details in post itself, please check my edited answer and let us know if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your actual Input is same as shown sample Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
sed 's/\(.*=\)\([^,]*\)\(,\)\([^,]*\)\(,\)\(.*\)/\1!\2\3!\4\5!\6/'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** As mentioned by OP words after `=` are NOT static then trying to provide the following solution on same.

***Case 1:***

```
cat Input_file
execution.commands=ARGUMENT,COMMAND,RULE
awk -F"=" '{num=split($2,array,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){val=val?val "," "!"array[i]:"!"array[i]};print $1,val;val=""}' OFS="="  Input_file
execution.commands=!ARGUMENT,!COMMAND,!RULE
```

***Case2:***

```
cat Input_file
execution.commands=ARGUMENT,COMMAND
awk -F"=" '{num=split($2,array,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){val=val?val "," "!"array[i]:"!"array[i]};print $1,val;val=""}' OFS="=" Input_file
execution.commands=!ARGUMENT,!COMMAND
```

Comment: They can have a different order and it's possible to have others arguments unfortunately (same for quantity).

Comment: @Robson, could you please check my edited solution(`awk`) now and let me know on same?

Answer (score 1):

You need this.

```
awk '/execution.commands/ && gsub(/[=,]/,"&!",$0)' file
```

or **sed**

```
sed -E '/execution.commands/s/([=,])/\1!/g' file
```

**That's it**